# Passing PHP variable to another PHP file with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

my problem is:  I have to pass a variable from a.php to b.php with an ajax call that take the variable 'numitems' from a.php and pass it to b.php...

My code is below but when I try to retrieve 'numitems' in b.php I receive this message:

> Notice: Undefined index: numitems in b.php on line 19

```
    stringaPost();        
    xmlHttp.open('POST', "b.php", true);    
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { 
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) { 
            data: {numitems : <?php $numitems;?> }
            document.getElementById("primaryContent").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
```

Instead in  b.php I have:

`$numitems = $_POST['numitems'];`

The problem is probably in the line with data: `{numitems : <?php $numitems;?>`
but I'm not sure and I can't figure out the root of the problem.

Comment: This should actually be:  `<?php echo $numitems;?>` or `<?=$numitems;?>`, but you're probably executing the script way before $numitems is being set.

Comment: Why `b.php` don't call `a.php` directly to get those variables ?

Comment: Read this I think Its Use Full for You.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637101/using-ajax-to-pass-variable-to-php-and-retrieve-those-using-ajax-again][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637101/using-ajax-to-pass-variable-to-php-and-retrieve-those-using-ajax-again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the data in the request rather than the success callback. As several other people have pointed out you are also missing an `echo` statement in your php.

```
stringaPost();     
xmlHttp.open('POST', "b.php", true);    
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { 
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) { 
            document.getElementById("primaryContent").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}; 
xmlHttp.send("numitems=<?php echo $numitems;?>");
```

Comment: Thank you, the last line was what I missed.

Comment: I would ask you another thing. We're in b.php and $numitems which is  $_POST['numitems'] should be increased by 1. So we do $numitems++ and after I would return it to a.php, How can I do this?
Thanks again

Comment: In b.php you need to print out the new `numitems` to the page where it will be obtained through `xmlHttp.responseText` in your `onreadystatechange` function. If you need to send back both the new number and something else you'll need to send both back by printing them to the page and then parse the returned page with javascript in the `onreadystatechange` function.