# onClick add to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have the below code, and I'm not sure if it even works. Basically, I want to do a like system, whereby when I click on the link, it adds a +1 to the user's likes.

I've tried so hard to read up but I just don't get anything, and I found a code similar below.

When I clicked on the link, it does process my insert.php page, but I don't know how to get the variable values...

What should I do? I'm not sure if the code structure below is correct...

Thanks!

```
<script>
function insertSalary()
{
    var salary = $("#salary").val();
    $.post('insert.php', {salary: salary}, function(data) 
    {
        $("#current-salary").html(data); 
    });
}
</script>

<div id="current-salary">
<a id="salary" onClick="insertSalary();">+1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: are u using ajax or performing a form operation ?

Comment: I suppose it's AJAX. There won't be a form, just a link called 'Like' and when clicked, it processes the +1 like. I just don't know where I can set my variable data. Like, where do I set the username to +1 to?

Comment: To get the variable value of a `post`, and taken from your `var salary...` code, use `$salary = $_POST['salary'];` that can later be used for database insertion or to write to a file with an incremented value using the `w` switch.

Comment: I want to know how I can assign values to them apart from doing `$.post('script.php', {salary: 100}, function(data){...});` since my js file will be external...

Comment: @user2509237 You can add a write to file function in your `insert.php`. Do you have the code for that file?

Comment: One thing I noticed if you happen to have found a solution, your `<a id="salary" onClick="insertSalary();">+1</a>` won't work. You will need to use `<a href="javascript:insertSalary();">+1</a>`. You left out the `href` and `javascript:`.

Comment: So anyone has a solution for my problem?

Comment: @user2509237 This link on SO could help a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799795/javascript-ajax-to-php-page-with-either-post-or-get

Answer (score 1):

The variable will be in your php script as `$_POST['salary']`

The value of salary is passed as part of the post method in jquery.

So you can do:

```
$.post('script.php', {salary: 100}, function(data){...});
```

and this will pass the value `100` to your php script as the salary value.

In php the $_POST and $_GET hashes contain the data that you pass with a given request.  In jquery $.post, $.get $.ajax create requests and take data hashes to build the data you want to pass with the request.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick reply! But how do I assign the values?

Comment: Am I able to assign the values in the link instead? I've seen like data-id="33" etc.

Comment: @user2509237 Are you asking for something to the affect of `$salary = $_POST['salary'];`. This assigns the variable `salary` as `$salary` from the POSTed value.

Comment: Yep.  Then you would access that data via `$('#element_id').data('id')`

Comment: @DanielNill Sorry but I don't understand how to implement that into my code D: Fred Yep!

Comment: you're going to have to give us some more information as to what you are trying to do.  There seems to be some confusion as to how javascript, ajax and php interact with one another.

Comment: @DanielNill I think the OP wants to use it for Facebook-related purposes. At least, that's what I'm under the impression from his question *"it adds a +1 to the user's likes"*. Or "Google". Hard to tell what his full intentions are, without seeing his full code/files.

Comment: @DanielNill I know how to process it in the PHP part. I just need help setting the VARIABLES. You suggested `$.post('script.php', {salary: 100}, function(data){...});` I'm going to be using the user id instead, so it'll be different for different profile pages... And since my js file is placed externally, how do I ensure that it shows the correct id on each page?

Comment: @Fred It'll be for my own system. +1 will be added to the user's database field for LIKES.

Comment: @user2509237 If your posted code works for you now, then all you need to do is use `$salary = $_POST['salary'];` or something to that affect implemented in your `insert.php` file, then implement a function to write to a file/database, that's it. You can then use `$salary` anywhere you want to, from thereon.

Comment: @Fred I know, I am talking about setting the user_id in my onClick. When you go to Fred's profile page, and click on the like button, I want it to add a like to FRED's database field. But how do I specify the USER_ID? I want my onClick to store the USER_ID. And my Insert will basically +1 to $_POST['user_id']

Comment: @user2509237 Then assign `salary` to `$_POST['user_id']`. `$salary = $_POST['user_id'];`. I'm not 100% certain about this, but, your `var salary...`; since `salary` has already been assigned by `var`, then it would make sense to use `$salary` as the variable and assign it to `$_POST['user_id']`, I would think.

Comment: @user2509237 Have a look at these posts on SO, may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130662/passing-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637101/using-ajax-to-pass-variable-to-php-and-retrieve-those-using-ajax-again

Comment: @user2509237 Maybe try something like this in your AJAX `var user_id = <?php $user_id = $_POST['user_id']; ?>` or `var user_id = post('user_id'); data: "user_id="+user_id,`.

Comment: But my AJAX file is external... I dont know how to set it when external.

Comment: I saw a site doing `<a id="salary" onClick="insertSalary();" data-id="3">+1</a>` or something, how can I do that?

Comment: @user2509237 `data-id="3"` is a **jQuery Mobile** related object. And the `<a` tag needs an `href`. Otherwise, it will NOT work. As in `<a href="page.php"`

Comment: @user2509237 Do as I did and Google **"Ajax text counter"**. That will get you started and point you in the right direction. If you can't be creative and know how code works, then you're wasting your time, including mine.

Comment: @Fred, this is incorrect.  `data` attributes can be accessed by jquery, and normal javascript. They are not related mobile jquery.  And @user2509237 will want `<a href="#">` as their href attribute as the links page reload functionality is going to be overwritten.

Comment: @DanielNill Btw, the `href` can also be left blank. Many including myself don't like having an `#` show up in my address bar.

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` and the page will not be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

While this may work, I would recommend separating your logic from your website by putting the javascript in an external file and then link your HTML page to it. 
I would also advise against declarative event binding which you have done by specifying 
**onClick="insertSalary()".** 

jQuery provides a method to pro-grammatically assign functions to events using the on method.
 So for your code, you could use:
**$('#current-salary').on('click', insertSalary());**

Comment: How do I go about implementing that? Does this mean my link would no longer require me to add onClick="bla()" ?