# Javascript/AJAX to PHP Page with either POST or GET

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, get

I have a javascript function with 2 values.  I want to post those values to a PHP page where I can update a mySQL database with it.  Here is what I have so far, which doesn't work.

```
function updateDB(page1,page2)
{
alert("TEST");

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: update.php,
page1: page1,
page2: page2
});
}
```

Update.php code

```
 <?php include "connect.php"; 
 $page1 = $_POST['page1'];
 $page2 = $_POST['page2'];

 mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET `page1` = '$page1'");

 ?>
```

When I run the function, I get a POP up but the database does not update.

Any suggestions?  I don't mind using GET or POST.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please show code from `update.php`, also try putting the url in single quotes such as `url: 'update.php'`.

Comment: To check if it should have worked, use `success: function() { alert("TEST"); }`.

Comment: Tried putting quotes.  Still nothing.  I've put up the update.php code

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Put the first page1 and first page2 in single quotes in addition to update.php

Comment: No errors.  I'll try the success function

Comment: Use `data: {page1:page1,page2:page2}`

Comment: I do get a success alert pop up.  I'll try using date {page1:page1}

Comment: a tip: always use WebInspector ( https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/ ) or Firefox ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to send data via POST with jQuery is with the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) property.

An example is:

```
function updateDB(page1,page2)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {
            page1: page1,
            page2: page2
        },
        success: function() {
            window.location = "http://google.com";
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

I have also added `alert` on success, as well as disabling cache. Even though this is post, IE will cache post requests to pages that have been requested with get.

I would highly recommend using MySQLi, or at the **very least** escaping the query:

```
include "connect.php"; 
$page1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page1']);
$page2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page2']);

mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET `page1` = '$page1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you want to change the page afterwards from the href simply do this:

```
<script>
    function linkme(_this) {
        window.event.preventDefault();
        //do all the code with ajax
        window.location = _this.href;
    }
</script>


<a href="http://google.com" onclick="linkme(this)">Clicky</a>
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot the single quotes. Does it work with the single quotes around the `url` property?

Comment: I get the success message.  But I don't get the update in the mySQL database.

Comment: Here is the mysql_query.  Can you check it?  mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET `page1` = '$page1'");

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="updateDB('<?php echo $page1; ?>','<?php echo $page2; ?>')">Click Here</a>

Comment: And the values are passed because if I run alert(page1), I get the page1 value

Comment: Use `mysql_query("UPDATE \`pages\` SET \`page1\` = '$page1'") or die(mysql_error());` and see if there are any errors.

Comment: @user1834218 Try this instead `<a href="javascript:updateDB('<?php echo $page1; ?>','<?php echo $page2; ?>');">Click Here</a>`, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tried the mysql_error().  But I never go to the update.php screen to see it.  There is nothing in error_log either.  Just some previous errors.

Comment: @user1834218 Actually, just `<a href="javascript:updateDB();">Click here</a>` should work if your code (Ajax) for the query is in the same page, least that's what I would think. Views anyone?

Comment: Press `f12` if you are on Chrome, or right click->inspect element on firefox. Check the console or networks tab to see the mysql error.

Comment: `<a href="javascript:updateDB('<?php echo $page1; ?>','<?php echo $page2; ?>')">Click Here</a>` Works perfect and updates the database perfectly.  However, is there anyway I can still link it to another page after it's clicked?  Would this work?  `<a href="http://www.google.com;javascript:updateDB('<?php echo $page1; ?>','<?php echo $page2; ?>')">Click Here</a>`

Comment: @user1834218 You will probably need to have a `header("Location: http://www.google.com");` after your executed query, I would think. Also, please add the `@` symbol in front of my name, just so I know you're addressing me.

Comment: Yes. Check the update, you can use `success`. Header in this case might not work because the page was called by `$.ajax`.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it onclick and not in the function?

Comment: Yeah you would need to `.preventDefault()`, and then follow the link found in the attribute of `href.

Comment: Could you write the code for that?  I'm not 100% sure what you mean.  I'm sorry about this.  I've been struggling with this code for hours before posting it here.

Comment: Check the edit, you just need to pass a variable to it, then preventDefault and redirect on `success`.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot '' at your strings(update.php and page1/2), which your browser console should wine about: "Uncaught ReferenceError: update is not defined". See more about debugging here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Also you need to put your data in an data object.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'update.php',
data: {
  page1: page1,
  page2: page2
}
}).done(function(data){
  alert('got:' + data);
});
```

Se more at jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/