# PHP / AJAX pass a form input and select value to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form and it contains basically of one input text box and one select...

Input box

```
echo '<input type="input" id="category_typex" name="category_typex" value="" />';
```

Select

```
echo '<select name="primary_cat" id="primary_cat" onChange="getSecondaryCat(this.value);">';
```

The Ajax code I'm using to pass the select is as follows:

```
function getSecondaryCat(val, cat_var) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "category-get-secondary.php",
    data:'secondary_cat='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
        $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
    }
});
}
```

I'm not being able to pass both the select and input values onto the next page....

I'm only able to pass the select value and not the input value

Comment: Use `$("#primary_cat").val()` in the function to get the value of the other input.

Comment: @Barmar How do I add it in my Ajax please?

Comment: Use **.ajax()** method and pass the argument in **json** format via **POST** http method, like this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15637150/4386714

Comment: @Barmar sir what is `cat_var` in `function getSecondaryCat(val, cat_var) {...}`

Comment: @KUMAR No idea. It's not used.

Comment: @Barmar sir `cat_var` is no use in the function `getSecondaryCat(val, cat_var) {...}` only `val` is enough?

Comment: @KUMAR Yes, of course. It never uses the variable, and it doesn't pass a value for it when calling the function.

Comment: @KUMAR I'm not sure why you're asking me, I didn't write the code.

Comment: @Barmar ok sir , sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getSecondaryCat(val, cat_var) {
    var category_typex = $('#category_typex').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "category-get-secondary.php",
        data:{secondary_cat:val, category_typex:category_typex},
        success: function(data){
            $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
            $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>');
        }
    });
}
```